# Extract blocks of text from a file and write each block to a new file using perl, but it is not working

Tags: perl

I have a large data file (text) that contains records from a database.
Each record is is delimited by "-" (146 of them) 
I would like to write the text between each delimiter to a new file based on data from that block.  The new file name should contain a piece of the data followed be the year (ie 2017)

For instance with this sample file:

```
1. 12/18/17                                                       
Company                                      
                     PAGE 2
    1:14 PM  GET                                              CURRENTLY SELECTED DEBTORS

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------- STATUS              **Acct:1234**       Disposition:9000 CANCEL                      Wait: 04/11/17

DEBTOR              Name:Doe John                         
Ssn:123456789   Cbr:  Ph:555-555-555
                      Rp:Doe John                           Ssn:               Rp Ph: 
                    Adr1:211 some road     POE:                      Lgl:   POE Ph: 
                    City:anytown                Cty:                     Canc:UNC  Born:01/01/1937
                      St: VA  Zip:54321        St:     Zip:             COF:N     Sal:

                    Clnt:00248 Someplace, 93076                         Org:    4
80.00
                    List:01/05/17 Srv:08/25/16 Pl95:    Time:9    Calls:0   Con:0   Bal:    480.00

Co-Maker's Previous Address Spouse's Previous Address MULTIPLE
ACCOUNTS RM# Acct      Name / Client     Chk# / Lst   Srv      Lpy  
Col Disp        Bal      Check Reason          Drivers Licen se #
      PRN      INT      LI3      LI4     AIN      CC     ATY      MS1     PJI 1   142424*   Doe John                                  
93076/00248/Somewhere  01/05/17 08/25/16            0 9000    
480.00
   480.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00

2. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So from the above is need to extract this block and write it to a new file named 1234_2017.txt based on the Acct:1234 data for that record- then move to the next block.  I have counted the number of records for the first file at 754 records, and I have a total of 10 files such as this.

```
#! / usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX 'strftime';

my $filename = "Facs_Data.txt";
my $outfile = "Acct_".strftime '%Y', localtime;
my $start = "'-' x 146";

open (INFILE, "<$filename"); open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile");

while ($start) {

  print $outfile;
  next
}
close (INFILE);
close (OUTFILE);
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code and some sample data. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for your question.

Comment: My suggestion would be - look at "input record separator" on perldoc. Then try writing some code, and asking a question when you hit problems.

Comment: @Flintlock: I've had a go at fixing the formatting of your input file and code. Please be more careful in future.

Comment: @Dave Cross - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to put any effort into explaining what you have tried, I'm not going to put any effort into explaining my solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '>' . ('-' x 146) . "\n";
my $year = (localtime)[5] + 1900;

# <> reads from STDIN or a filename given as an argument
while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/; # Ignore empty records (like the first one)

  my ($acct) = /Acct:(\d+)/;

  my $file = "${acct}_${year}.txt";
  open my $fh, '>', $file
    or die "Can't open $file: $!\n";

  print $fh;
}
```

Comment: It's also possible that the asker isn't interested in any explanation.

Comment: Thanks - maybe I am not asking the proper question or just the wrong way.  What I have tried is next to nothing because I am not sure how to do what I need other than define a start point, and the infile and outfile.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am at a loss how to explain this any better maybe I can scrub some of the data and remove personal information.  I will edit my original post.